# ¿Cómo añadir linea de tendencia exponencial y coeficiente de correlación a mi gráfico?

Tags: r

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
data <- read.csv(file="data.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
plot(data$var1, data$var2)
```

En `plot()` he omitido otros argumentos que uso para dar colores el grupo al que pertenece cada punto, formas del punto, ejes y demás.

Me sale el siguiente plot.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se aprecia, es una curva exponencial. En Excel me sale una R2=0.99. Me gustaría superponer la curva exponencial, indicando la R2. Es decir, incluir la línea de tendencia. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo? Y además ¿Cómo puedo mostrar el coeficiente de correlación sobre el gráfico?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una forma simple es usar [`smooth.spline()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/smooth.spline.html), prestar atención al parámetro `spar` que define que tan "suave" va a ser la línea.

```
# Generamos datos de prueba
set.seed(100)
n <- 100
x <- seq(n)
y <- rev(rnorm(n, 50 + 40 * x^(-0.3), 1))
Data <- data.frame(var1=x, var2=y)

# Plot
plot(y ~ x, Data)
smoothingSpline = smooth.spline(Data$var1, Data$var2, spar=0.1)
lines(smoothingSpline, col='red', lwd=3)
```

Salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con `smoothingSpline = smooth.spline(Data$var1, Data$var2, spar=0.7)`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]